# Java cucumber Selenium : NullPointerException for scenario.write for the first scenario on before tag

Tags: java, selenium, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber

I am getting the NullPointerException when the code below code is executed.
Note that the exception is recieved **only** for the **first** cucumber scenario executed.
There is **no** exception for the **second** scenario.
I am actually trying to insert the timestamp before start of each scenario.
Please advise how this issue can be fixed.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
@Before //cucumber.api.java
public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario1)
{
this.scenario=scenario1; //I would need this for a later use.
scenario1.write("Start Time:"+new Date()); //Nullpointerexception

}
```

I tried  this as well, but the same error.

```
@Before //cucumber.api.java
public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario)
{
this.scenario=scenario; //wont matter if i have this or not
scenario1.write("Start Time:"+new Date()); //Nullpointerexception

}
```

Comment: You'll have to explain how some one can reproduce this. You may want to start from scratch with a new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was unable to find a direct answer.
However As an alternative : i avoided writing on "scenario" in @Before

```
@Before //cucumber.api.java
public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario)
{
startDate = new Date(); //defined globally
}

@After//cucumber.api.java
public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario)
{
this.scenario=scenario; 
scenario1.write("StartTime:"+startDate);
scenario1.write("End Time:"+new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method should not be static.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, the method in my code is not static. its only a typo when i typed it here.